# jScrollPane not showing in div #container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-jscrollpane

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/sZaxc/9/). I am making a grocery list web app, and I am trying to make the div `#container` have a jquery jScrollPane scrollbar. When I add the script src's and add `$('#container').jScrollPane({showArrows: true});`, the scrollbar doesn't show up.

HTML (entire body):

```
<div id='top'>Kitchen List</div>
<br />
<div id='container'>
<input type='text' id='input'><button id='click'>Add</button>
<ol></ol>
<div id='error'>Please enter a grocery item<br /><button id='eb'>Close</button></div>
</div>
```

CSS (entire style):

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #252525;
    color: #96f226
}
#top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #96f226;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #252525;
    position: relative;
    position: fixed;
}
#container {
    margin-top: 40px;
}
#input {
    background: #4a4a4a;
    border: 1px solid #454545;
    color: #96f226;
}
#input:hover {
    background: #656565;
}
#input:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px #96f226
}
#click {
    background: #4a4a4a;
    border: 1px solid #454545;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #96f226;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#click:hover {
    background: #656565;
}
#click:active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px #96f226;
}
#click:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px #96f226;
}
#error {
    height: 55px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: orange;
}
#eb {
    background: orange;
    color: red;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer
}
#eb:hover {
    background: #e59400;
}
#eb:active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px #e59400;
}
#check {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #4a4a4a;
    cursor: pointer
}
#check:hover {
    background: #656565;
}
#check:active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px #96f226
}
#check.active {
    background: #96f226
}
```

JS/JQuery (just for the scrollbar):

```
$('#container').jScrollPane({showArrows: true});
```

Comment: join jsfiddle collaboration [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/sZaxc/9/#&togetherjs=0pLMgIuuwu)

Comment: Should you not have `overflow: auto` in the CSS for `#container`?

Comment: I have added `overflow: auto` and it is still not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following to the css for container:

```
#container {
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**Edited**

You need to create a reference to the jScrollpane object, using the `data('jsp')` method:

```
var contentPane = $('#container');
contentPane.jScrollPane({showArrows: true});
var api = contentPane.data('jsp');
```

And then once you have appended new content, you call the `reinitialise()` method against the jScrollpane object:

```
api.reinitialise();
```

[Updated Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/bu3Vq/6/).

Comment: adding more content wouldn't be very wise on an online website.

Comment: @JJP - not sure what you mean. Scrollbars will only appear if there is content to scroll through.  One input field and a button won't do it.

Comment: You understand that as you add dynamic content and that content extends beyond the height of the div, the scrollbar will then appear?

Comment: Yes, I do. But when you add enough items, the content should grow big enough to display the scrollbar.

Comment: Ah, so the problem is with dynamic data being added. See updated example on how to update the pane.

Comment: but how would you do this without adding default content? I just want the scrollbar to appear when you have enough list items. I don't want content adding without it being added by the user

Comment: Just put the `reinitialise` at the bottom of the click event.